# Could not remove an element assigned to Uploadify object

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I called a simple Uploadify plugin and used it in javascript like:

```
      $("#file").uploadify({
         'uploader': 'Scripts/uploadify.swf',
         'cancelImg': 'Content/Images/cancel.png',
         'buttonImg': 'Content/Images/upload-icon.png',
         'auto': true,
         'method': 'post',
         'script': '/Home/Upload',  //path to MVC controller
         'fileExt': '*.gif',
         'fileDesc': 'Gif only (*.gif)',
         'multi': false,
         'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
            $(filenameAfterUpload).html(fileObj.name).show();
            $(this).remove();
         },
         'onError': function (event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
            alert(errorObj.info);
         }
      });
```

I want that after uploading file, the upload button (itself) must be removed and `fileUploaded` must be visible (it will on success function)

```
<div class="upload-block">
    <%=Html.LabelCustom("logo", "Logo") %> <!-- this is my custom helper-->
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <span id="fileUploaded" class="hidden"></span> <!--I defined in CSS the hidden class-->
</div>
```

I want that `#file` must be removed/hidden. I tried `$(this).remove();` but it doesn't work.

Of course, the upload system works fine but this part `$(this).remove();` doesn't work.

I won't mention that Uploadify doesn't work (neither upload system) in IE8 because of SWF.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it work with `$('#file').remove()`?

Comment: no, it doesn't work. I created that Uploadify object into generic function to be used in many places.

Comment: I understand it's not a long-term solution, just trying to see if the problem is with `this` or something else. When you say "it doesn't work" do you mean it doesn't remove the element and there is no error of any kind? Do you have this up somewhere we can see it in action?

Comment: The mechanism works properly but that `$(this).remove();` doesn't work which means it won't remove itself. I want to remove this element (the input html which is type = 'file') after successful upload.

Comment: Are there any errors in Firebug or other Javascript debugger? Does this work? `onComplete: function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data) { var that = this; setTimeout(function(){$(that).remove()}, 0);}`